# How do I use bijections in combinatorics?

Tags: combinatorics

I am struggling really hard with the following assignment:

a) Show that
$$
\#\{(a,b,c)\mid a,b,c\in\mathbb{N}, 1\leq a<b<c\leq n\}=\binom{n}{3}.
$$

b) Show that
$$
\#\{(a,b,c)\mid a,b,c\in\mathbb{N}, 1\leq a\leq b\leq c\leq n\}=\binom{n+2}{3}.
$$

The hashtag stands for cardinality.

We are supposed to use bijections and for b) the set {a,b+1,c+2}.

I really have no clue how to do this and would appreciate your help!

Comment: a can take on any value from 1 to n- 2.

Comment: okay, but how do I write down a solution in terms of a bijection?

Answer (score 2):

If you can create a bijection between two sets, then they have the same cardinality.  So, a common method for solving counting problems is to show that your set stands in bijection to a set that is ostensibly easier to count.

For instance: can you see how the set in (a) stands in bijection with the collection of subsets of $\{1,2,\ldots,n\}$ of size $3$?

For (b), call your set $B$.  Can you relate $\{(a,b+1,c+2)\mid (a,b,c)\in B\}$ to your answer from part (a)?

Comment: Thanks for your edit and the reply! I can definitely see how set A stands in bijection. However I have no idea how to "show" that in mathematical terms.  It's the 4th week of my first semester :D

Comment: To show there is a bijection between the sets, you need to (a) give a function for the bijection, and (b) prove that it is bijective.  What is the appropriate function in this case?  That is, what is the set that corresponds to a triple $(a,b,c)$?  Why is this mapping injective (that is, no two triples map to the same set?) Why is it surjective (that is, why does it hit every such set)?

Comment: Okay, I will try my best! Thank you very much for the help!